# put todays date in array

Tags: php, arrays, mongodb, date, datetime

I know you can do this by hand, but that is not the point of this. I need away to put todays date in my mongoDB query and get it to work.

By hand the following works fine.

```
$cursor = $collection->find(array("date"=> array('$gt' => '01/10/2013')));
```

however when I use the following

```
$date = date('d/m/Y');
$cursor = $collection->find(array("date"=> array('$gt' => '$date')));
```

It does not work

I have tried

```
$cursor = $collection->find(array("date"=> array('$gt' => $date)));
$cursor = $collection->find(array("date"=> array('$gt' => "'".$date."'")));
$cursor = $collection->find(array("date"=> array('$gt' => \"$date\")));
```

none of the above worked

Comment: Try using a `MongoDate`: http://php.net/manual/en/class.mongodate.php

Answer (score 0):

That doesn't look right to me. And I don't think your '01/10/2013' criteria is working the way you expected it.

How is the "date" field stored? If it is stored as a MongoDB date field then you have to construct a MongoDate object and use that in your search.

```
<?php
$insertDate = new MongoDate(strtotime("October 2nd 2013"));
$collection->save(array("date" => $insertDate));

$date = new MongoDate(strtotime("October 1st 2013"));

$collection->find(array("date" => array('$gt' => $date)));

?>
```

See also http://php.net/mongodate

Comment: Also note that you should not have single quotes around PHP variables, see http://us2.php.net/language.types.string